# Bootable usb gone haywire

Tags: usb, liveusb

I know it sounds like repeat questions but it’s not hear me out first. Thanks in advance!

So I was trying to install Android x86 on a USB stick. I partitioned it with bootable ntfs. Installation worked ok. It installed grub loader too. Now when I tried to boot from my USB it gave me grub error 17 which is already known issue with wrong partition  problem. So I decided to go back to Ubuntu and re flash the USB stick but when I tried to do it it didn’t recognise my USB. Now I’ll tell you guys what I have tried.

1. Gparted. First thing for re partitioning. USB won’t show up.
2. Fdisk (not working either) (I tried modprobe USB_storage command too)
3. Windows disk part and diskmgmt.msc (windows actually shows USB stick in devices and printer but fails to start it with error code 10)

I don’t know what else I can use if even diskpart and fdisk can’t help. Thanks again!

Comment: The thumb drive may simply have died. If it doesn't show up on another PC, it's dead.

Comment: Oh no! That’s the worst case scenario! Plus after booting from USB my Ubuntu also gone haywire which directly goes into busybox shell for manual block checks. I guess I’m stuck with a dead USB and slow windows for a while.